# STM32 f401re power issue?

Tags: stm32

I get the following error when I try and upload code

Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: No device found on target.

The voltage is across VCAP1 is 0 which I find a bit odd.

[image: Schematic]
[image]

I have alligned the chip as per the data sheet which can be seen in the following photo.
[image: board placement]

I am quite lost any help would much appreciated. I would think it is a power issue seeing as there is no voltage across VCAP 1? I dont belive I have fried the chip as this is the second attempt and I used anti static bags during transport and earth mat when soldering and assembling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I found the answer. Naturally 5 minutes after posting this. I hadn't set up the reference voltage. Being used to AVR I was not aware that I needed this before programming it.